# How to capture PR CREATION event in bitbucket

Tags: bitbucket

‘’’’
Need to know if there is any possible way to capture the event of pull request creation in bitbucket to write a custom script using this event.

Dont want PR to trigger any automatic build instead just need capture the pr creation event to write a custom python script to trigger certain activities through  script run.

One option is to read/continuous poll the bit bucket PR creation page to identify the activity/event but it sounds to be a bad scripting standard and not a good practice.

Is there any git command to identify PR creation at feature branch and to merge into parent(say its DEV) and also git command to capture PR default reviewer names???

So that, these git commandS can be used in script To track if any PR is raised?

Verified many websites and read many articals and unfortunately no where found the possibility to capture the PR creation event in bit bucket?

Great if anyone can post the possibility to capture the event to write our own custom logic with the PR event capture
‘’’’

Answer (score 0):

PR is not a part of git. It's a concept unique to code hosting sites like Bitbucket, Github, etc. Therefore, theoretically it's not possible to capture PR creation event using git tool alone.

You can poll the [Bitbucket REST Apis](https://developer.atlassian.com/bitbucket/api/2/reference/resource/repositories/%7Bworkspace%7D/%7Brepo_slug%7D/pullrequests) for the PR list. The response is in Json format, stable and easy to parse, so it's not really a bad practice (as when you parse the raw html).

Another way is to set up a Bitbucket webhook that triggers on PR creation event. You then need to run a web server (something like [this](https://github.com/adnanh/webhook)) to accept the webhook call and run the corresponding scripts.

Comment: We need to send an attachment via email for which python script is ready. But it has to happen when developers create a PR request in BB.we tested BB REST API's to capture PR reviewer default list, it worked fine. how to do we understood but WHEN TO DO is the question. Polling BB server 24*7 all the time no one  knows when developers decides to create PR in BB. give your though on how to capture the PR event(how to capture that event). I feel its promising to have webhook in BB as your 2nd option, let me know if webhook can be created to trigger a script in server and add PR list in email CC

Comment: Have another thought, polling(Reading BB's audit log), look like audit log would get updated up on PR creation, every event will be registered in log, can it be used to trigger the script ? also how about an options in BB itself to trigger a batch script up on PR creation(again it is going towards webhook), does webhook have option to trigger any batch file by setting the hook rules as PR creation?

Comment: Polling the Bitbucket rest api every 5 minutes for new commits is what some CI tools I know do. Depending on your case, you can set the interval to something like 1 minute. There will be a delay (polling nterval) from when the PR is created till the email being sent but for most the use cases I've encountered, that delay is generally acceptable.
There will be a request rate limitation (~1000/hour) for Bitbucket Cloud but here I assume you are using BB Server (since you mention audit log), in that case I guess there will no rate limitation and you can perhaps set the interval as low as 10s.

Comment: About whethere BB can run a script by itself upon PR creation event, for Bitbucket cloud, afaik there is no way to do that. For BB Server, I'm not sure, but I suggest you look through the Atlassian Market (https://marketplace.atlassian.com/addons/app/bitbucket)